# Compress a large integer to a small integer

Tags: java

I am trying to find a way to compress a large number to an another number. The input number could contain 30 to 45 digits. Digits range between 0 to 9.

The compressed result should have maximum 24 digits long. Also, result should be a NUMBER only.

For Example:

Input: 1123456789013956410078121395641007812 --> Total 37 digits

Output: 1245785478547  --> Total 13 digits. (It a imaginary result only.)

Note: Output should contain digits 0 - 9 and can have max 24 in length.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: It's impossible if large integers are arbitrary ones: there are only 1e24 different values you can have as results, but 1e45-1e30 == 1e45 different sources. So one to one (compressing) function is impossible.

Comment: Agreed with @DmitryBychenko Let's say you compress the input, how would you decompress the output to get the original input?

Comment: As @DmitryBychenko says, the pigeon hole principal says that this is impossible

Comment: @Kai: Sorry, I am new here. The question is: I need to compress a large number to another small NUMBER itslef. Digits will range between 0-9. Input number's length could be 35 to 45 digits long, and Output should be max of 24 digits long. Please refer the example.

Comment: @user3459791 By what criteria? I mean you could divide the number by 100000 and you lose 5 digits. But you won't be able to get the original back

Comment: @user3459791 your requirement is under-restricted. Strictly speaking `return 1` currently fits your requirement, as you have not really defined by "compress".

Comment: @user3459791 thats again no question...only the criteria which code you need. But no examples what you have tried or a more specific question. no one here will write the full code for you. but anyway itsimpossible to solve with your criteria.

Comment: @Cruncher: I need the original number back. Could you please tell in detail about "return 1" ?

Comment: @user3459791 pls read the comment of Dmitry Bychenko. There are much more possible numbers to compress than possible outputs you want to have. So its IMPOSSIBLE to solve. There are collisions soyou can get the original number back.

Comment: uless you KNOW some input combination will never happen, that way you can "re-map" input to output

Comment: And indeed if you did solve this problem in general (which is provably impossible) then you would be a very rich man. You could compress anything into a single digit number by repeating this kind of process. Now do you see how rediculous this sounds?

Comment: When you use 24 digits, you have used every possibly combination of 0 to 10^24 - 1 by using those numbers.  You should be able to prove to yourself that you can't add even one more number and not duplicate a number you already have.  What you can do is encode a 45 digit number into 24 bytes using BigInteger.

Comment: You can *in some cases* compress numbers according to your criteria, for example, if you have number like 1234512345123456123451234512345. it all depends of number source entropy. If you need theoretical background, read [Shannon's source coding theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%27s_source_coding_theorem) and [Data compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are looking for a custom hash function to process your input number.
You can use any number of available integer/string based hashing algorithms or write your own method. Looking at the input data it seems your input a string of number rather then a integer data type. One example would be

```
public long getHash(String input)
{
int hash=<any prime number>;
for (int i=0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    hash = hash*<any large prime_number>+charAt(i);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks mig-25 foxbat. And how to get the original data back?

Comment: @user3459791 hashing is a irreversible transformation. once you a hash a value we cannot get back the original value from the hash value. you should retain your original value programmtically.

Comment: When you compact data this way, it is lossy compression.  There is no way to get back the original value.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler strategy is to encode the number as a double and convert it to a long

```
public static long asLong(String s) {
    return Double.doubleToRawLongBits(Double.parseDouble(s));
}
```

This has the advantage that you can at least get back the magnitude and first 16 digits of the number. (And it uses no more than 19 digits)

Consider a simpler problem, You want to compress two digits into one digit and you start at the start

```
0 => 0
1 => 1
....
8 => 8
9 => 9
10 => ?? there is no more symbols you can use.
```

Compressing 25 or more digits into 24 digits is also impossible for the same reason.

---

Another logic puzzle; if you can compress 45 digits into 24 digits, you should be able to compress 24 digits into 14 and 14 into 8 and 8 into 4 and 4 into 2 then 1.  This would allow you to represent every possible number with one digit.  Does that sounds plausible to you?

Now you can do this, if you don't need it to be reversible.  Sum all the digits of the number, sum all those digits until you get just one digits.  However you can see that if you say `5` as a result you can't turn this back into a 45 digit number which sums to 5 (or sum of sums is 5)

Comment: `However you can see that if you say 5 as a result you can't turn this back into a 45 digit number which sums to 5 (or sum of sums is 5)` Well you can. It's just unlikely that you'll get the same number back

Comment: @Cruncher It could be that `5` is just `5`

Comment: It could be yes. But it could also be `11111 * 10^40` which some algorithm could produce from 5

Comment: In fact there should be ~10^44 possible numbers.

Comment: I think it's *exactly* 10^44 actually :). But yes, that was my original point